# Solve the recurrence relation given by $a_n = 5a_{n−1} + 6a_{n−2}$, for all $n \geq2$, with $a_0 = 1 $and $a_1 = 3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

According to my solution, $A_n = \dfrac{2}{5}6 ^n + \dfrac{-3}{5}(-1)^n$.

Where the roots are $6$ and $-1$, $A = \frac{2}{5}$, and $B = \frac{-3}{5}$

Just looking to see if this is correct, no other answers for specific setup on web. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try calculating $a_2$ according to your solution?

Comment: You can check your solution on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%2B1%29%3D5*a%28n%29%2B6*a%28n-1%29%2Ca%280%29%3D1%2Ca%281%29%3D3). It finds
$$a_n=\frac{1}{7}(3(-1)^n+3^n 2^{n+2})$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I solve it, I get different A and B.

Try checking your calculations, the overall idea seems fine.

$a_n = (4/7) \cdot 6^n + (3/7) \cdot (-1)^n$

Comment: I agree, so $+1$

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

to $a_n=5a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}$ leads to $$r^2=5r+6\\r^2-5r-6=0\\(r+1)(r-6)=0\\\to \\a_n=a(-1)^n+b(6)^n$$and initial conditions $a_0=1 \to a+b=1\\a_1=3 \to -a+6b=3$ it seems 7b=4 $\to  b=\frac 47\to a=\frac37$

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check by yourself:

$$a_0=\frac25-\frac35\ne 1.$$

---

Let the roots be $r,s$. We have the system

$$A+B=a_0,\\Ar+Bs=a_1$$

solved by

$$A(r-s)=a_1-sa_0,\\B(s-r)=a_1-ra_0.$$

> $$7A=4,\\-7B=-3.$$